# Wordpress Crashes - 3.9.2

Tags: php, wordpress

I have noticed that when using MAMP PRO, and creating a local database I get an error when changing a wp-admin field:

- Tagline

The website installs correctly and runs fine untill I change the tagline, I have not changed the theme or created a post / page or category.

[image]

If you change the field data the you get redirected to the wp-admin screen. Then on page login the error is shown. You cannot load specific page and the root of the website (logged in or logged out) just remains white. I cannot view-source at any time. Nor do I get a 5-- server error.

Can someone double check this. It is driving me mad.

Regards,

-Neil

Comment: I suggest you submit a bug report to the wordpress site: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is more suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/